# Linq to SQL: DataTable.Rows[0]["ColumnName"] equivalent

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

Consider this:

```
var query = from r in this._db.Recipes
            where r.RecipesID == recipeID
            select new { r.RecipesID, r.RecipesName };
```

How would i get individual columns in my `query` object without using a for-loop?

Basicly: how do I translate `DataTable.Rows[0]["ColumnName"]` into Linq syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to go about it:

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();

var recipe = (from r in dc.Recipes 
              where r.RecipesID == 1
              select r).FirstOrDefault();

if (recipe != null)
{
    id = recipe.RecipesID;
    name = recipe.RecipesName;
}
```

Comment: You can use either Single() or First().  The difference is that Single() will throw an exception if your LINQ query returns multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

It's really unclear what you are looking for, as your two samples are compatible.

As close as I can figure, what you want is:

```
var rows = query.ToList();
string name = rows[0].RecipesName;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string name = this._db.Recipes.Single(r => r.RecipesID == recipeID).RecipesName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misunderstood your question.  As others are saying, you can use ToList() to get a List back.  An alternative if all you need is the first one, just use:

```
query.First().ColumnName
```

or if you want to avoid an exception on empty list:

```
var obj = query.FirstOrDefault();
if (obj != null)
   obj.ColumnName;
```

---

Original Answer (so the comment makes sense):

Use [Linq to Datasets](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2007/01/26/querying-datasets-introduction-to-linq-to-dataset.aspx).  Basically would be something like:

```
var query = from r in yourTable.AsEnumerable()
select r.Field<string>("ColumnName");
```