# How to get column names from table returned from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns a table. The stored proc is called via a linq datacontext.

It works fine and I get the table back however I really want to also get the title relating to each particular cell returned.

Does anyone know how to do this?

The stored procedure call is like:

```
var table = DataContext.GetTable().ToList();
```

So I get a `List<GetTable>`. The data is fine I just want the column names as well.

Comment: Do you mean the column names? Can you post the code that calls the stored procedure?

Comment: Possible repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187357/linq-to-sql-datatable-rows0columnname-equivalent

Comment: @Oded I added the code. Yes I did mean column names.

Comment: @Coder: What does `GetTable()` return? A DataTable?

Comment: @Coder 2: GetTable() is not a type, it's a method.  What does it return?

Comment: @Coder: If you right click on GetTable and click Go To Definition, you can see the return type of the method.

Comment: It returns List<GetTable>. When I look at each item in the List it is of type GetTable. I think this is due to LINQ getting an anonymous type and giving it the name of the stored procedure.

Comment: Mark Avenius GetTable() returns a table generated by a sql select

Comment: Mark Avenius I clicked on 'Go To Declaration' and it says: ISingleResult<GetTable> GetTable(). This was generated by LINQ into the datacontext.

Comment: @Coder: I see. Sorry, I missed that it was coming from Linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **use reflection** to do this

```
var columns = table.First();

var properties = (from property in columns.GetType().GetProperties()
                  select property.Name).ToList();

foreach (var property in properties)
    Console.WriteLine(property);
```

You can also use the  **Meta Model**  in the [System.Data.Linq.Mapping Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.aspx)

```
AttributeMappingSource mappping = new System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributeMappingSource();
var model = mappping.GetModel(typeof(MyDataContext));


MetaFunction function = model.GetFunction(typeof(MyDataContext).GetMethod("MyStoredProc"));


foreach (var resultTypes in function.ResultRowTypes)
{

    foreach (var column in resultTypes.DataMembers)
    Console.WriteLine(column.Name);

}
```

Since Stored procedures can have more than one result set this is probably the better way since it handles that case.

Comment: Doh, I've been working on a pure reflection solution and was working well in my tests and somewhat robust.  But using the `MetaModel` is much nicer.  Though I noticed that you'll have to filter out associations and use the `MappedName` instead (in the case of a renamed column).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using reflection on the entity types.  As far as I can tell, all generated properties correspond to the columns in the table if they have an associated `ColumnAttribute`.  You can try this:

```
public static List<string> GetColumnNames<TEntity>(Table<TEntity> table)
    where TEntity : class
{
    return GetColumnNames(typeof(TEntity));
}

public static List<string> GetColumnNames(DataContext context, string functionName)
{
    var retType = context.GetType().GetMethod(functionName).ReturnType;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(retType.Name == "ISingleResult`1");
    return GetColumnNames(retType.GetGenericArguments().Single());
}

public static List<string> GetColumnNames(Type entityType)
{
    return (from p in entityType.GetProperties()
            let columnAttribute = p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                   .OfType<System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute>()
                                   .SingleOrDefault()
            where columnAttribute != null
            select columnAttribute.Name ?? p.Name)
           .ToList();
}

// usage:
// from a function/procedure name
var names1 = GetColumnNames(DataContext, "GetTable");
// or by entity type directly (the return type of the function/procedure)
var names2 = GetColumnNames(typeof(GetTable));
```

---

In light of seeing Conrad's use of the meta model, I came up with this.  Associations (added by LINQ to SQL) would need to be filtered out to get the column names from the table.

```
public static List<string> GetColumnNames<TEntity>(Table<TEntity> table)
    where TEntity : class
{
    return new System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributeMappingSource()
        .GetModel(table.Context.GetType())
        .GetTable(typeof(TEntity))
        .RowType
        .DataMembers
        .Where(dm => !dm.IsAssociation)
        .Select(dm => dm.MappedName)
        .ToList();
}

public static List<string> GetColumnNamesMeta(DataContext context, string functionName)
{
    var type = context.GetType();
    return new System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributeMappingSource()
        .GetModel(type)
        .GetFunction(type.GetMethod(functionName))
        .ResultRowTypes
        .SelectMany(rrt => rrt.DataMembers
                              .Where(dm => !dm.IsAssociation)
                              .Select(dm => dm.MappedName))
        .ToList();
}
```